# How to add name attribute in dynamically generated HTML form?

Tags: javascript, django

I am generating a dynamic input field in my form using javascript in Django template.

But on submitting the form in Django, I need the `name` attribute in every input field.

Like this:

For input field with From Area label I need a name to be something like this: `fromArea-1`
Similarly, For input field with To Area label I need a name to be something like this: `toArea-1`

Any help would be beneficial.

Here is my code:

```js
function addRow() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'card';

    div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>From Area</label>
                     <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <label>To Area</label>
                     <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Distance</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
                </div>
        </div>
    `;

    document.getElementById('permission-wrapper').appendChild(div);
    }
```

```html
<div class="mt-4 ml-4 mr-4">
    <form class="mt-4" method="post">
    <div id="permission-wrapper">
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>From Area</label>
                     <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <label>To Area</label>
                     <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Distance</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" onClick="addRow()">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to make this work?

Comment: I have tried to add a random number using Django to its name.
But then again it's completely random, and I am not able to distinguish between fields.

Comment: Why random? Why not just increment a counter and assign names using the counter?